# Unable to connect AWS EC2 instance via browser-based SSH connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS. First time I when created my AWS account, I created an AWS linux EC2 instance and connected to it via browser-based SSH connection. It was straight forward and there was no error. Then I terminate that instance and created a new Ubuntu instance. Now I can't connect to it like before. I got this error.

[image]

Why could this happen? Is this something to do with AMIs? or keypairs?

Comment: Does your instance have a public ip?

Comment: @Stargazer Yes I hope so. I can see a IPv4 Public IP

Comment: Is port 22 open?

Comment: @Stargazer Yes. In inbound section it is opend. But it is the only port opened.

Comment: Are you using correct username? Note that `ec2-user@...` is for AWS Linux and `ubuntu@...` is for Ubuntu.

Comment: @MatusDubrava I think that also correct. It's ubuntu.

Comment: @Stargazer is this some thing to deal with AMIs?

Answer (score 0):

in some cases for new accounts, instance launch and termination can be throttled or delayed by aws to ensure no malicious activities, try again in 2 hours and hopefully, your issue will be solved.

Comment: Question is about not being able to connect to an instance, not about being unable to launch an instance.

Comment: 1) please make sure your instance in public subnet 2) make sure your security group have port 22 accessible  3) make sure the instance in a healthy state

Comment: Hi, what does this means 'please make sure your instance in public subnet '

Comment: Hello, Public subnet means that it has access to internet gateway using the NAT table :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html